# Is there a jquery plugin to make it to dynamically add textfields in a webform

Tags: jquery

I am seeking a jquery plugin to dynamically add textfields in a webform by clicking a 'add' icon. The number of the textfield is arbitrary. Does anybody knows some jquery plugins that can do this?

Comment: Umm… The core of this is insanely trivial. `$('#add').click(function () { $('form').append("<label> Foo <input name="bar"></label>"); });`. What would a plugin do, other then put limits on the flexibility of the markup you generate?

Answer (score 2):

Do you really need a plugin for that? You can use [`append`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) to append content to an element:

```
$("#button").click(function() {
   $("#yourForm").append("<input type='text'>"); 
});
```

The argument passed to `append` can be an arbitrary string of HTML, a DOM element, or a jQuery object (if, for example, you wanted to clone an existing `input` and append that).